# Weird bridge monitoring event when vlan aware bridge configured

Tags: networking, bridge

I Configured a VLAN aware bridge on my system with the command:

```
ip link add <bridge_name> type bridge vlan_protocol 802.1Q vlan_filtering 1
ip link set dev <bridge_name> up
```

Later, When adding another bridge link (`ip link add name yoav type bridge`) and using "bridge monitor" we can see the log event:

```
7a:26:53:bb:86:e5 vlan 1 master * permanent (mac address of the bridge link).
```

What is the meaning of this event? why there is no **interface**?

the same can be seen while reading netlink messages of type RTM_NEWNEIGH - ndm_ifindex is 0.

Thanks!